# How to correctly install pytorch?

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

I get the following error when importing pytorch:

```
python -c "import torch; print(torch.version.cuda)"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/vision/anaconda3/envs/psf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 197, in <module>
    from torch._C import *  # noqa: F403
ImportError: /home/vision/anaconda3/envs/psf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so: 
undefined symbol: _ZNK3c1010TensorImpl23shallow_copy_and_detachERKNS_15VariableVersionEb
```

These are the relevant package versions:
[image]

I installed pytorch through

```
pip3 install pytorch==1.10.1 torchvision==0.11.2 torchaudio==0.10.1 cudatoolkit==11.3 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

and my cuda version is:

```
nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_May__3_19:15:13_PDT_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.3, V11.3.109
Build cuda_11.3.r11.3/compiler.29920130_0
```

Please I need help

Comment: Use the commands at https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/. There is no `cudatoolkit` pip package. Also which operating system are you using and version?

Comment: I would suggest creating a new conda environment with the command at https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/.

Comment: Thx, but now I get ```python -c "import torch; print(torch.version.cuda)" None```
Also in running a training I get
```ImportError: /home/vision/anaconda3/envs/psf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cuda_cpp.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3c104cuda20CUDACachingAllocator20notifyCaptureDestroyEiSt4pairIyyE```

I am on Ubuntu 20.04